# Have versus Has

Tags: word-usage

Which is correct?

For example, is it

> "When one of you *have* a moment, please..."

or is it

> "When one of you *has* a moment, please..."

Comment: _One_ of you, like _one_ of the children, is singular. Which should answer your question.

Comment: "One" is singular, so you must use the third person. However, both those sentences are nonsensical without more context and seem to be incomplete.

Comment: @MorganFR i wouldn't call it nonsensical - it may be ungrammatical (I'm not sure) but the meaning in context could be very clear - imagine a manager saying it to a group of chattering employees, for example, to mean "When you've finished wasting time, i need someone to actually help me do something"

Comment: Thank you for the responses.I did not use the entire sentence and this website would not accept an ellipsis after "please..." within my question body.

Answer (score -3):

They both sound okay to me.  "Have" is okay, it seems, because it agrees with a second person singular "you", and each one of you is a "you" -- second person singular.

This predicts that if I were addressing a person not in the group, since none of the group was addressed, "have" could not be used.  Even though "have" is plural and there are several people in the group referred to, it is not plurality that licenses "have" in the original example, but rather that "have" agrees with second person that matters:

```
When one of them has a moment, please.  
*When one of them have a moment, please.
```

Comment: One of you is always singular, it cannot be "have."

Comment: @MorganFR I don't agree with you. When you have tens of audience (students, for example) looking at you and you say, "If one of you have a problem,..." I think it could be used. Subject-verb agreement in English is not black and white and there is no hard-and-fast rule. Also, I don't understand why this answer deserves six downvotes.

Comment: @GregLee I think it would be better if you could edit your answer and specifically mention some context where "have" could be used.

Comment: @Rathony, my answer gets lots of down votes because most people without training in linguistics can't tell a fact from a theory.  They know a theory according to which the agreement here should be singular "has", and for them, that makes it true that the agreement must be singular "has".  I frequently notice this in comments and answers.